# Bootstrap submit button not aligning within form on non-mobile devices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Within my rails form: I am using `form-horizontal`.  I can't seem to figure out how to line my submit button up within my form.

The submit button does line up when accessing the form from a mobile devise:

[image: on mobile devise]

But the submit button is not aligned when accessing the form from a tablet/computer:

[image: button not aligned]

Here is my code for the form:

Search Providers

```
<%= form_tag providers_index_search_results_path, {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :title, nil, class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <%= text_field_tag :title, nil,  class: "form-control col-sm-5" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :name, nil, class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <%= text_field_tag :name, nil,  class: "form-control col-sm-5" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
  </div>


  <%= button_tag('Submit', class: "btn btn-primary") %>


<% end  %>
```

How can I make it so that the submit button lines up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your button inside of a `div.form-group`, and subsequently in the grid.

Here is the example from the bootstrap docs:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Always check the docs first: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal